# integrating java web apps from development to production

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, production-environment

I developed a web application Using java EE 6, its a very small web application for a starting business organization,

I did all the testing on it for performance, correctness, and so on, and we bought a server for hosting our web application and did all the necessary work (static ip, application servers set up... etc.)

Now, I want to move it to production stage, what is the difference between production and development environments? and how to change the stage of the project (application) from  Development Environment to Production Environment?

(i.e how to move the application from my local machine to the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so there is any difference between production and developement enviroments. Moreover, everyone tries to keep developement enviroments indetical (or very similar) to the production one.

Production means only that on this particular environment people work instead of developement and test environments where developers/testers are doing their jobs...

Answer (score 3):

Create a WAR file and deploy it on the production server.  Set up any JNDI lookups you need on the production server.  It should be no different from your local setup.

I'm assuming that the service you're paying for is not just a web server (e.g. Apache or IIS).  You need a Java servlet/JSP engine at minimum or a full-blown Java EE app server.  Is that what your agreed to with your provider?

Comment: yes exactly its a full-blown java server machine, but my question is whats the diffrence between both environments

Comment: Should just be the databases, email servers, and other resources you point to - nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

the difference between those environments, is that you usually put more resources on the production servers (more memory, more disk/database storage, CPU capabilities, clusters, etc) than the development env since that "production" environment is going to be used by end users on a potential daily basis, and you don't want any to find your server down do you?.

In the other hand, the development environment is meant to be used just by the development team, it doesn't need as many resources as the production one because the development is something measurable and relatively small and, if in any case, the server is down at a specific moment, you can boot it up again and you won't receive any complain about absence of service from your clients.

However, as other answered, both environment should be as identical as possible (same app server, same database server, etc), just with different hostnames.